# Is it possible to send a file from Swift app to callable function in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do an API with [Callable Functions from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), and I'm willing to send some user data from my iOS/Swift app to a Cloud Functions with a picture like:

```swift
userData: [
  name: 'Alisson Enz',
  age: 26,
  ...
  picture:???(Data/Base64/...),
]
```

Is it possible to send it to my server through Cloud Functions? If so, what's the limit of data that I can send to Firebase Cloud Functions in a single call?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a file to a callable function is not really a great idea unless its content is very small.  The underlying protocol for callable uses JSON.  You would have to convert your file to a string using base64 or some other encoding, and that would just make the file even bigger.  A callable function is just an HTTP function with extra stuff wrapped around it, so it's subject to the same [10MB payload limit](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits).

In general, you're probably better off uploading the file to Cloud Storage, then sending a path to the file that was uploaded to the callable.  Or, possibly even better, upload to storage, and use a Storage trigger to invoke your code.  You can put additional information in the custom metadata of the uploaded file as needed.

Comment: Thanks Doug, but that's exactly how I'm doing it right now, but my problem is that I wanna save the data in the Firestore Database once with everything so I can run a Cloud Functions onCreate to send an email to the user with their picture. Now I need to run an onUpdate function and check if there is a picture so every new user I run 2 times the same function. And in some cases, the user does not upload an image. What should I do? haha

Comment: In a storage trigger you can add data to realtime database.  That's not hard.  And you can trigger the email too just like you would in the database trigger.

Comment: In the future, I wanna implement a webhook is it ok doing this way? Isn't it going to be a mess in the future?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You should be able to reuse code if you've engineered it well.

Comment: We're building a SaaS for over 1 year, and everything is on Firebase. The system is getting bigger now, so I'm trying to simplify some Functions in the server and improve our documentation. And as we are a Saas, in the future we are planning to create a webhook and an API, that's why I'm trying to create a standard pattern in our system. BTW check it out at w3lcome.com :D

Comment: All I can really tell you is to do whatever meets the needs of your project.  Things can and do change over time.

Comment: Thank you very much Doug